# How to mask countor plot over basemap python?

Tags: python, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I want to draw a contour map with basemap-python. I used contour and contourf functions I have data over the land but ı want to mask these datas. Contourf is self masked with basemap but contour is not ? How can ı mask contour plot like contourf ?  Here the image link : https://pasteboard.co/Iegz6ql.png

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.basemap  you can use fillcontinents  function with zorder. You should give a higher zorder number then contour's zorder .